# Long Update Layer Tree - how to keep it from being updated on every style change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm hoping you guys can help. I'm struggling to remove the jank from my web app, and after a couple days of troubleshooting, I've found that "Update Layer Tree" is all that's standing in between me and a smooth 60fps.

My web app uses fixed position divs being controlled by javascript to make a player piano (the "playing" of the notes is simulated with one long transform on the container div).  What I've noticed is that any style change anywhere on the page is causing the entire layer tree be updated, at quite a performance cost. After combing through all the resources online I don't quite understand how to step around this.

Here's a live example page. https://pianu.com/waving-through-a-window
[enter image description here][1]

With Update Layer Trees well over 20ms throughout. 
[enter image description here][2]

Here's how the page looks in the Layers tab in chrome.

[enter image description here][3]

I'm excited to learn more about how layers update and composite in the browser, but I definitely need some help. I'm not a developer by trade.

Thanks!